# Validate by breakpoints in pug

Tags: pug

I want to know if I can validate according to breakpoints a div be shown or not.

```
#Carousel.carousel.slide(data-ride='carousel')
  .carousel-inner
      .carousel-item.active
        video(muted='')
          source(src="video.mp4", type='video/mp4')
```

I want when screen be less than 760px, be shown another video(videoresponsive.mp4)

```
#Carousel.carousel.slide(data-ride='carousel')
  .carousel-inner
      .carousel-item.active
        video(muted='')
          source(src="videoresponsive.mp4", type='video/mp4')
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use CSS media queries for this.

Comment: Not at all, as I'm pulling the images dinamically from the API.